# How to filter results based on dependencies between two columns in one table and results from another table in R?

Tags: r, data.table, tidyverse

I am wondering if there is a way (a function or just few elegant lines of code) that can help me filter results with this troublesome data frame structure/ column dependency.

I have a scenario where I have features that are highly correlated with each other (i.e. table 1).
I also have a separate table that lists another score for each individual feature (i.e. table 2).

**Table 1:**

```
feature1, feature2, feature_correlation_score  
a, b, 0.7      
c, d, 0.5  
b, a, 0.7   
d, c, 0.5     
e, f, 0.8,  
f, e, 0.8
```

**Table 2:**

```
feature, label_correlation_score       
a, 0.20    
b, 0.15    
c, 0.08   
d, 0.04  
e, 0.02   
f, 0.02
```

**What I want to do is:**
**(1)** Identify each unique `feature1` and `feature2` pair (i.e. a, b and b, a are the same).
**(2)** Then examine what the `label_correlation_score` is from table 2 for each value in a pair, and only keep the feature that has the highest `label_correlation_score` between each unique pair.
**(3)** Store the results in a new table that looks like this:

**Final table:**

```
feature, label_correlation_score  
a, 0.20  
c, 0.08  
e, 0.02
```

**Note:** it could be either e or f selected in the last row because their `label_correlation_scores` are the same.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** I'm also interested in what the equivalent code using `data.table` would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are okay with using the `tidyverse`, here's one approach.

- First, we keep only rows for which `feature1` is less than `feature2`, thus removing duplicates (assumes both versions are always available).
- Then, we join the `label_correlation_score` for both `feature1` and `feature2` (giving the columns suffixes `_1` and `_2`, respectively).
- Then, we store the largest score in the `label_correlation_score` column and the feature corresponding to this in the `feature` column.
- Finally, we keep only the `feature` and `label_correlation_score` columns.

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- read_csv("feature1, feature2, feature_correlation_score
a, b, 0.7
c, d, 0.5
b, a, 0.7
d, c, 0.5
e, f, 0.8,
f, e, 0.8")

df2 <- read_csv("feature, label_correlation_score
a, 0.20
b, 0.15
c, 0.08
d, 0.04
e, 0.02
f, 0.02 ")

df1 %>% 
  filter(feature1 < feature2) %>% 
  left_join(df2, by = c("feature1" = "feature")) %>% 
  left_join(df2, by = c("feature2" = "feature"), suffix = c("_1", "_2")) %>% 
  mutate(label_correlation_score = pmax(label_correlation_score_1, label_correlation_score_2),
         feature = if_else(label_correlation_score_1 > label_correlation_score_2, feature1, feature2)) %>% 
  select(feature, label_correlation_score)
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  feature label_correlation_score
  <chr>                     <dbl>
1 a                          0.2 
2 c                          0.08
3 f                          0.02
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked a treat. The line `filter(feature1 < feature2) %>%` is very nifty (I would not have thought about it this way in my workflow because my feature labels were so long and most share prefixes with each other). I also didn't know that `base::pmax()` existed and its use case.